# How to tell if a mouse/keyboard doesn't have on-board memory?

Tags: malware, firmware, keyboard

How to tell if a mouse/keyboard doesn't have accessible on-board memory? I know if it has: there are tells like custom macro buttons for example, and I was told by A4tech support: if a mouse doesn't install any drivers - it doesn't have on-board memory! So that would mean no accessible firmware to which you could write! I Am asking, because some mice/keyboard have on-board memory to which you can write a virus, even it is extremely unlikely...

Comment: welcome - i think your question could be better focussed if you spent a little time thinking about the threats you want to counter - the only way to tell if a piece of hardware has on-board storage is by dismantling it, but i expect your concern is more "how can the onboard storage be utilised for some unintended purpose"? - for argument's sake, let's say i convince you to use this awsom keyboard here, into which i've installed a sensitive microphone and persistent storage ...

Comment: The claim that if a mouse doesn't install any drivers, it doesn't have on-board memory is (a) imprecise and (b) incorrect.  If a message sent by a mouse causes your computer's OS to install a driver, is it the mouse installing the driver or the OS?  What if it causes an already-installed driver to be loaded?  What if the driver is incorporated into the OS and not a separate component?  What if one driver is installed automatically but a different one can be installed (in its place or in addition) to enable more commands?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could the USB-Receiver of a wireless mouse/keyboard be a security risk?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/264491/could-the-usb-receiver-of-a-wireless-mouse-keyboard-be-a-security-risk)

Comment: Thanks for an answer, I will just keep separated keyboard/mouse.